# Django Query when returning multiple fields

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a model which I would like to change the `return` field from a single field to a concatenated string of fields. I have done this and it works fine, the issue comes when I try and query the foreign key related to that model.

### Current Code

**Models.py** *- Items App*

```
class Details(models.Model):
    serial_number = models.CharField(max_length = 300, unique=True, null = True, blank = True)
    manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length = 300, null = True, blank = True)
    model_type = models.CharField(max_length = 300, null = True, blank = True)
    equipment_type = models.CharField(max_length = 300, null = True, blank = True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["serial_number"]

    def __unicode__(self):  # Python 3: def __str__(self):
        return self.serial_number
```

**Views.py** *- Instruments App: Query*

```
queryset = InstrumentAnnual.objects.get(instrument_details__serial_number = self.object.instrument_annual, current_revision = True)
```

**NOTE:** *'**InstrumentAnnual**' model has a foreign key to '**Details**' model called '**Instrument_Details**'*.

### New Code

**Models.py** *- Items App*

```
class Details(models.Model):
    serial_number = models.CharField(max_length = 300, unique=True, null = True, blank = True)
    manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length = 300, null = True, blank = True)
    model_type = models.CharField(max_length = 300, null = True, blank = True)
    equipment_type = models.CharField(max_length = 300, null = True, blank = True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["serial_number"]

    def __unicode__(self):  # Python 3: def __str__(self):
        return u"%s %s %s" % (self.manufacturer, self.model_type, self.equipment_type)
```

So my issue is how do I query the above model through a foreign key as it no longer returns `self.serial_number` so I can't use `__serial_number` in the query.

My desired result is just to display `manufacturer`, `model_type` and `equipment_type` in the foreign key drop down instead of just a potentially meaningless serial number. If I am going about this the wrong way please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What? That model is exactly the same, and it still has a serial number. The only difference is in the `__unicode__` method which has nothing whatsoever to do with querying.

Comment: Hi, sorry I thought it did (still learning!). When I use the same query it fails saying there's no matches however with the 'current' code it works.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to do the queryset the way you currently do it. If you want to get the InstrumentAnnual object that belongs to a Detail object, you can simply use `self.object.instrumental_annual` (given that `self.object` is your Detail object, as it it in your example.

As to how to fix your provided query, you are currently checking for a serial number with the string representation of the InstrumentAnnual object. But that isn't your serial number anymore. Instead you would do this

```
queryset = InstrumentAnnual.objects.get(instrument_details__serial_number = self.object.instrument_annual.serial_number, current_revision = True)
```

to specify that you in fact want to check the serial number. But as already said, there is no need for this queryset, as you can easily get the InstrumentAnnual object through `self.object.instrumental_annual`